# I'm having some display issues with feature image, how can I make this image's width 100% and responsive with the existing code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

This is the site I'm currently working on: http://perlaparra.com/rnr/site/

I've set the width to 100%, and still not displaying in full width. I appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you!
P :)

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers helped! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap framework gives an width to the `.container` elements .

please remove this class and also remove `left:-10px`from `.featured` div

Answer (score 0):

Because your image is into **'container'** class.
if you want to set your image 100% full width then bring your image about to **'container'** class & add below code in css:

```
.featured img{width:100%;}
```